# Can I use Visual Studio Professional with Team Foundation Server 2008?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008

Can I use Visual Studio Professional with Team Foundation Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say the version of the Visual Studio. For general things like version control, work items, team builds you can definitely use VS 2005/2008 Pro with TFS 2008.
However if you are using VS 2010 beta 2 things are a bit different.

Check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/teams_wit_tools/archive/2009/10/19/compatibility-matrix-for-2010-beta-2-team-foundation-server-to-team-explorer-2008-and-2005.aspx) for a full compatibility matrix.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, provided you have a client access license (CAL) to use Team Foundation Server.

You will have to install the client tools (Visual Studio Team Explorer), which comes packaged with Team Foundation Server.

Comment: the Team Explorer installer is also available at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

You will have to clarify what you mean by "use."  Certainly some features no, others yes.

Comment: Well I have a group of developers that all have VS 2005 and 2008 and I want to get them into some better source control. I wanted to know if after I purchase team server 2008 and the cals for them, if I am also going to have to update each developers visual studio as well?

Comment: I know this will start a huge debate, but if you goal is simply better source control, don't go to the expense of TFS, especially if your team is fairly small (like less than 20).  TFS is targeted at "enterprise" type development groups.  If you're just looking for better source control look at an alternate like SVN/Tortoise/AnkhSVN